# What are proper status codes for CORS preflight requests?

Tags: http, cors, http-status-codes, preflight

What status code should a well-written HTTP server return when it gets a CORS preflight (`OPTIONS`) request?

`200`, `204` or something else?

Should the status code be different in case origin is allowed (and corresponding headers will be set) or not allowed (and CORS headers will not be set or will not match the origin)?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The gist of it is, just use `200`.

A little more generally: You should just send back the same status code for the CORS preflight `OPTIONS` request that you’d send back for any other `OPTIONS` request. The relevant specs don’t require or recommend anything more than that.

What the specs say: The Fetch spec at https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/ is where requirements for the CORS protocol are defined, and it says the status can be anything in the range `200`-`299`.

That’s from the [CORS-preflight fetch algorithm](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-preflight-fetch), in [a step saying it can be any “ok status"](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#ref-for-ok-status):

> If a CORS check for *request* and *response* returns success and *response*’s status is
>  an [ok status](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#ok-status), run these substeps: …

And as far as what an “ok status” is, the spec says this:

> An **ok status** is any status in the range `200` to `299`, inclusive.

Beyond that though, the Fetch spec doesn’t recommend any particular status within `200`-`299`.

The other relevant spec here is the HTTP 1.1 spec, which has a section defining semantics of all HTTP response status codes, and within that, [a section that defines *Successful 2xx*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3) codes.

And within that section there’s [a specific section for *200 OK*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.1), which says this:

```
The 200 (OK) status code indicates that the request has succeeded.
The payload sent in a 200 response depends on the request method.
For the methods defined by this specification, the intended meaning
of the payload can be summarized as:
…
OPTIONS  a representation of the communications options;
```

So a response to a CORS preflight OPTIONS just needs to be:

- an indication that the request has succeeded
- a representation of the communication options (which in this case includes the [`Access-Control-Allow-Methods`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Methods) and [`Access-Control-Allow-Headers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers) response headers)

That’s what [`200 OK`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.1) is defined by the HTTP spec to be, so you can stop right there.

But if you read through [the rest of the `2xx` codes in that section](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3), you can confirm the semantics of none of them make sense for an `OPTIONS` response—except for [`204 No Content`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.5).

Now as far as `204 No Content` goes, there’s nothing *wrong* with using it for `OPTIONS` responses—but there’s also not really any point. That’s because:

- unlike for some other methods, the HTTP spec defines no use for an `OPTIONS` payload
- therefore in practice, clients don’t expect any payload (content) to come back for an `OPTIONS` (and wouldn’t do anything with any payload that did come back)

…so there’s no practical purpose in using a specific `204` status code in an `OPTIONS` response to explicitly tell clients there’s no payload.

> Should the status code be different in case origin is allowed (and corresponding headers will be set) or not allowed (and CORS headers will not be set or will not match the origin)?

No. There’s no standard-defined code other than `200` or `204` you could use anyway—but regardless of that, the specs don’t require it to be any different and don’t define any different use if it is. And think about it: What is any existing client code going to do any differently due to any difference in the status codes for those two cases?

If the answer to that is, *“Nothing”*, then there’s no point in making it different.

---

Given all the above, the bottom line is: just send `200 OK` for CORS preflight `OPTIONS` responses. Sending any code other than just `200 OK` isn’t necessary or useful.

Comment: `204 NO CONTENT` seems appropriate here.  Why not use that?

Comment: @blz In their answer, Mihai says that Firefox rejects 204 preflight responses. I am not sure about Firefox, but for example [this page](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html) says: "some legacy browsers (IE11, various SmartTVs) choke on 204".

Answer (score 17):

I used **`204`**. Now it's not working cross-browser anymore. Use **`200`**.  Firefox started rejecting CORS requests if **`204`** is received in the preflight.  It wasted me almost 2 hours debugging it.

Lesson to learn: When in doubt about web standards don't choose what makes sense spec wise(i.e. `204` for no content)...choose what most people do(the easy/stupid choice)

Comment: I just lost a morning to this, debugging code that I had written using the previous answer above that recommends 204. I wonder how many developer hours were lost over this nitpicky change.

Comment: @Mihai do you have a context on why 204 in OPTIONS would mess up a GET request? It seems like an issue with a couple of browsers/os/device unique combination.

Answer (score -1):

I am using basic auth passed through headers from an AJAX call and both Firefox and Chrome are using 204 for (preflight/options).

[image: FireFox Network panel]

[image]