# I can't use json to make a Post request to my web api using react

Tags: ajax, reactjs, cors, fetch, asp.net-core-webapi

I created a webapi in ASP.NET Core, and I need to consume it using React, the web api works normally, if I use curl or postman among others, it works normally. The problem starts when I'm going to use React, when I try to make any requests for my API with js from the problem.

To complicate matters further, when I make the request for other APIs it works normally, this led me to believe that the problem was in my API, but as I said it works with others only with the react that it does not. I've tried it in many ways.

The API is running on an IIS on my local network

### Attempted Ways

### Using Ajax

```
$ .ajax ({
    method: "POST",
    url: 'http://192.168.0.19:5200/api/token',
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader ("Content-type", "application / json");
    },
    date: {
      name: 'name',
      password: 'password'
    },
    success: function (message) {
        console.log (message);
    },
    error: function (error) {
        / * if (error.responseJSON.modelState)
            showValidationMessages (error.responseJSON.modelState); * /
            console.log (error);
    }
  });
```

### Using Fetch

```
const headers = new Headers ();
    headers.append ('Content-Type', 'application / json');

    const options = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers,
      body: JSON.stringify (login),
      mode: 'cors' // I tried with cors and no-cors
    }

    const request = new Request ('http://192.168.0.19:5200/api/token', options);
    const response = await fetch (request);
    const status = await response.status;
    console.log (response); * /
    // POST adds a random id to the object sent
    fetch ('http://192.168.0.19:5200/api/token', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify ({
      name: 'name',
      password: 'password'
     }),
    headers: {
      "Content-type": "application / json; charset = UTF-8"
    },
    credentials: 'same-origin'
    })
  .then (response => response.json ())
  .then (json => console.log (json))
```

### Using Request

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest ();
    request.open ('POST', 'http://192.168.0.19:5200/api/token', true);
    request.setRequestHeader ('Content-Type', 'application / json; charset = UTF-8');
    request.send (login);
```

### ERRORS

**Console**
[image]

**Network tab**
[image]

> When I do this without being change the content type to JSON it works
>   because the API returns saying that it is not a valid type.

Comment: No "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" ...the problem in your API, I mean it comes server-side, not the client-side

Comment: But When I try using post man or curl it works property

Comment: you should read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36250615/cors-with-postman

Comment: I changed my IIS configuration to allow CORS too and I didn't succeed, Do you have any ideia?

Comment: Have you tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44379560/how-to-enable-cors-in-asp-net-core-webapi

Comment: You also need to allow OPTIONS requests. Apart from CORS.

Not sure about .NET, but in Laravel I created a middleware which returns 200OK to all options requests

Comment: I already allow OPTIONS request on IIS, I'll take a look if I can change anything on the web api code.

Comment: @NguyễnThanhTú I had a look on your suggested link, And I added CORS in my web api code too, and now the  request returns 204(No content), but It should return anything.

Comment: 204 (No content) is the response to the OPTIONS request, and it’s a proper response — because the OPTIONS response has no response body

Answer (score 2):

Apart from allowing CORS in you .NET configuration. You also need to return 200 OK for all OPTION requests.

Not sure how it's done in .NET but just create a middleware that detects the METHOD of the request, and if it's OPTIONS, the finish the request right there with 200 status.

Comment: This is correct, though more precisely, the status code can be any 200-209 status code — it doesn’t have to only be 200. A lot of servers return 204 for OPTIONS. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46026409/what-are-proper-status-codes-for-cors-preflight-requests/46028619#46028619

Answer (score 0):

Well I had the same issue and it seems that you need to add the **action** to the **HttpPost** attribute in the controller.

Here is an example.

```
    [HttpPost("[action]")]
    public void SubmitTransaction([FromBody] SubmitTransactionIn request)
    {
        Ok();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try like this

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 { 
     services.AddCors();
 }

 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
 {
        app.UseCors(option => option.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowCredentials());

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseMvc();
 }
```

Comment: It is very insecure, is it not?

Comment: Just to try whether this code is working, If it is working you can able to customize the url